# Clang-format do not change function arguments or parameters

Tags: c++, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

When the arguments or parameters of a function was intentionally formatted a certain way and it is not exceeding the column limit, clang-format should not change anything, e.g. this function definition should stay as it is:

```
int formattedFunction(int foo1, int foo2,
                      int bar1, int bar2, int bar3,
                      int x, int y);
```

Is there any way to tell clang-format to just keep the format of arguments/parameters (without adding single-line-comments).
I know something like this is possible if ColumnLimit is set to 0 but we explicitly don't want that.